# Azure - How to change FTP pasword

Tags: azure, ftp

I'm new to azure platform.

I create everything and ftp and now have:
[image]

But where to find FTP password and change it?
I try export template but there I have:

```
"osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachines_roomtobid1_name')]",
                    "adminUsername": "perica",
                    "linuxConfiguration": {
                        "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
                        "ssh": {
                            "publicKeys": [
                                {
                                    "path": "/home/perica/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                                    "keyData": "ssh-rsa AAAAsssssssssssssssssssssssssssskDAtnpBC/mM4VPlpzM4E6uLNFssGBjJGHwziCo9a/VfCfv1cRusdasdasXCt9erWh/N+R3YHXF6rfGkt2YOaWVr6bxpxLFTFlM3+KL2sZ8NcR0FF/bxjMkbatdpkp3gAI8ll0M72UL3GQpw1cRIPMukONgVYgO8yGsAQLQJnCe8UONcUducsi1n+egLYxRVI7gnfL9j6PiHWzJTx+IRgLz1t4nk7OQ=="
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "secrets": [],
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('virtualMachines_roomtobid1_adminPassword')]"
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaces_roomtobid1128_name'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_vm2296_name'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaces_roomtobid1128_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
```

Where to find my FTP password?

Comment: also I need to say that sFTP work good but I need FTP for some WP plugins

Comment: EH? Did you installed an FTP Server on your VM? Or is it included in the selected image?

Comment: yes I install ftp connector and add to VM